# does iPhone has a directory to store the file of mail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

HI, everyone,

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. I want to write a file management app for iPhone. However, I don't know the file basic operation of the iPhone. for example, when the user download a text file/png, where do the file stoer? And is it possible to get the file out of the store place and retrieve the data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know app data is app specific. There should be no way for you to browse through other app's data, including mail.

The best I think you can hope to get is to register some kind of handler in Mail so that data can be transferred to your app by Mail (GoodReader can do that with some extensions), or make your app connect to the mail server.